# Radio Button not functioning properly when sent in email

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I have a form with 2 sets of radio buttons. One with 5 options, the other with 2 options. The form works well. but when i click submit, the email only shows the first option instead of the choice chosen by user. Where is the fault in this code?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Products</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" id="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 1" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" id="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 2" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" id="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 3" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 3</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" id="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 4" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 4</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" id="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 5" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 5</label><br>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="radio" name="EnqTitle" id="EnqTitle" value="Mr." required="required" checked onkeypress=chkEnter(event);><label for="EnqTitle">Mr.</label>
    <input type="radio" name="EnqTitle" id="EnqTitle" value="Ms." required="required" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);><label for="EnqTitle">Ms.</label>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var currentTime = [];
    var score = 0;
    var value;



    $( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {


        params = {
            "Products":$("#Products").val(),
            "EnqTitle":$("#EnqTitle").val(),

        };

        console.log(params);

        $.ajax({                
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'form.php',
                data: params,
                dataType: 'json',
                complete: function(data)
                {
                    window.open('Thank You.html','_self')                 
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: @SimoneRossaini it still didnt work. it still shows for option 1 when i chose option 3.

Comment: I know, I thought he meant a multi-choice

Comment: @MahadevanRajendran you can accept answer if its satisfying your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code - e.g. you cannot have multiple elements with the same id - this is invalid in HTML. And ID must be unique - otherwise logically it is not an ID!!

And, more importantly for your problem:

```
params = { "Products":$("#Products").val(), "EnqTitle":$("#EnqTitle").val(), };
```

is incorrect, because it always selects the element with that exact ID. Since you have got multiple elements with that ID, only the first one will be considered valid, and that one will always be returned. The others are ignored, because it's expected that there can only be one element with a specific ID. This is not how you find the selected option of a radio button.

Luckily for you, it's also unnecessary. Just write

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

in the AJAX options instead, to have jquery automatically collect the form data for you - see https://api.jquery.com/serialize for details

Here's a demo showing the serialization process

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").submit(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).serialize());
    return false;
  });
});

function checkEnter(event) {
  //dummy
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Products</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 1" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option2" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 3" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 3</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 4" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 4</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Products" class="form-check-input" value="option 5" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);>
    <label for="Products">option 5</label><br>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="radio" name="EnqTitle" value="Mr." required="required" checked onkeypress=chkEnter(event);><label for="EnqTitle">Mr.</label>
    <input type="radio" name="EnqTitle" value="Ms." required="required" onkeypress=chkEnter(event);><label for="EnqTitle">Ms.</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem here. It should be like this:

```
params = {
     "Products": $("input[name='Products']:checked").val(),
     "EnqTitle": $("input[name='EnqTitle']:checked").val()
};
```

Comment: Yes although OP could just serialize the form and remove this code entirely